# POS for "Just when [you thought...]"

Tags: grammar, terminology, clauses

I'm having a brain fart.

> Just when you thought it was safe to go back in the water

Can you remind me what "Just when" is?

It changes "You thought it was safe to go back in the water" from an independent clause to a dependent clause, but I can't remember the name of its function.

UPDATE: Is it just an adverbial phrase? Or does it have a different name? Does the type of "sentence" have a name when someone uses it independently or is it just a fragment?

Comment: It's just when you have an unfinished trope that can be understood without being completed.  It's an adverbial subordinate clause modifying the unstated "it's not."

Comment: I thought you were asking about its etymology, despite the grammar tag :)  I was going to suggest the movie *Jaws*... ho hum.